# HttpGet to get results generated by JavaScript?

Tags: android, httpclient, http-get

I am requesting results from a page like this:

```
String getURL = "http://www.example.com/search.php?q="+query;
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
if (resEntityGet != null) {  
    String response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
}
```

The problem is, the `<results>` div in the page (the `<div>` that contains the search results) is empty. I know it is because of *the results being generated by JavaScript.*

- Is there a way to modify my code to solve it?
- If not, is there another way to do it -- beside modifying the way the back-end works?

Comment: What exactly is the problem ?

Comment: `The problem is, the <results> div is empty because of the results being generated by JavaScript.` -- That's the problem.

Comment: No way to do this using Http request. It has been a dream of scrappers.
By the way, closely check the JavaScript code that populates the div, know how it works and see if you can do it. If the Javascript code does AJAX, do it from your code... There is no generic case here

Comment: @iturki ok ok, sorry I didn't get the point